# Is it possible to transfer data retrieved using facebook Graph API to a database in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I have an ASP.net Web project that includes a form and a Database.
When a user register to the site (not from facebook) he has a username, and then when he fills the form, I can add this username to the 'username' column in the database (using User.Identity.Name). When he login using facebook, I can't do it. So I thought to use his facebook ID, since any ID is different, but I can't find a way to do it. I tried to retrieve the ID using response.id, set the value in a Label, and then to get the Label content from the codebehind to transfer it to the DB, but it didn't work. here is the code I tried:

Set the ID into the label:

```
  function testAPI() {
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,gender,age_range,picture.width(45).height(44),location', function (response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('HiddenFacebookID').innerText = response.id;
});
```

}

The Label:

```
<asp:Label ID="HiddenFacebookID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

The code-behind:

```
conn.Open();
            string insertQuery2 = "INSERT INTO UserData (username) values (@username)";
            SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(insertQuery2, conn);
            com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", HiddenFacebookID.Text);
com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The Label content is really the facebook-ID, but the database gets NULL. Please Let me know if I wasn't clear.
I will appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're setting in JavaScript isn't being posted back to the server.  Only form values are posted to the server.  And an `asp:Label` doesn't render as a form element.

Use a hidden form field instead:

```
<asp:Hidden ID="HiddenFacebookID" runat="server"></asp:Hidden>
```

And set its value in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('HiddenFacebookID').value = response.id;
```

Basically, regardless of the lies that WebForms has been telling for years, HTML content is *not* posted to the server when submitting a form :)  Only form values are.

Comment: Works amazing. Thank you so much!